# Best way for launching html/jsp to communicate with GWT module

Tags: javascript, gwt

I asked this at the GWT forum but I'm impatient for the answer and I seem to get rather good responses here.

A html or jsp file is used to launch the xxx.nocache.js, which then
decides which browser "permutation" to use.

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
 <title>xxx</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="xxx.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
```

In my case, I am using a jsp. When the JSP is executed, it discovers
some conditions. I wish to pass these conditions as values to the
GWT module being launched. The "elegant" GWT way to pass
these values would be to persist them as
request/memcache attributes and then have the GWT module perform RPC
to retrieve those values.

For example, the JSP discovers that
the current user is Whoopy. Shouldn't I simply have the JSP generate
javascript to store

```
user = "Whoopy"
```

as a top or namedframe level javascript variable and use JSNI within the module to
retrieve the value for user?

I have not tried it yet, but I would like to know how anyone might have done it without having to use RPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't I simply have the JSP generate javascript to store user = "Whoopy"

YES, you should. Its always best to reduce RPC calls for performance reasons.

Take a look at the [Dictionary](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) class. It allows you to read JSON strings stored in the HTML without resorting to JSNI methods. Its meant for just this purpose